# windows phone 8 LongListSelector group mode default margin

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

im working with LongListSelector in group mode. problem is whenever group is enabled ,the right hand container holds a default margin i think ,so my data template dont get the full width ,i need to cancel the default margin.

so my basic need is to have a group enabled LongListSelector whose data template will hold the full width of the screen .

[image]

Comment: can you post screen shot?

Comment: ive added the screenshot,im using the default longlistselector example from toolkit. here i gave the data item template a background of green and i want this area to hold the entire width of the screen.but you can see on right and left hand side,there is some default margin which has background of indian red.

Comment: set margin of the pivot to 0 as by default it is 24

Comment: it removes the left side margin,but right sided margin still remain.

Comment: it is by default there put it minus